# Shadowmap texture alpha

Tags: three.js

Is it possible to fix the shadow map problem below? Basically the shadowmap doesn't seem to respect the alpha test. The shadow is of the tree planes geometry and not of the leaves. Would this be something to do with depth-write perhaps?

I am just using a standard 
`THREE.MeshPhongMaterial`

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When casting shadows, objects are treated as solid from the point of view of the light.

But what you can do is specify a `customDepthMaterial` that utilizes `alphaTest`. This custom depth material is used in the shadow calculation.

There is an example of this technique here: http://threejs.org/examples/webgl_animation_cloth.html.

three.js r.63