# Can a plane cast shadow on another plane in Three.js?

Tags: three.js, webgl, shadow

I have a plane with a transparent PNG (a world map).
**Can I cast shadows from one plane onto another plane?**

I am having no success with this code:

```
plane = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.PlaneGeometry(200,200), new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({color: 0xcccccc}));

var mapTexture = new THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture("img/map_transp2.png");
    mapTexture.needsUpdate = true;
    var mapMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
        color:0xaaaaaa,
        transparent:true,
        map:mapTexture,
        side:THREE.DoubleSide
    });

mapPlane = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.PlaneGeometry(800/5,370/5), mapMaterial);

plane.receiveShadow = true;
mapPlane.castShadow = true;
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16246023/shadowmap-texture-alpha/16246261#16246261

Answer (score 0):

Transparent parts of the mesh should be handled differently if they're written in texture.
Take a look at this example: http://threejs.org/examples/webgl_animation_cloth.html

Answer (score 0):

Your two planes are on the same z value. Give them some distance with:

```
mapPlane.position.z = 100;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// You need also to set this: 

renderer.shadowMapEnabled = true;

// and also you need to add a light and enable its shadow, for example, 

sLight = new THREE.SpotLight(0xFFF4E5,1);

sLight.position.set( 250, 250, 250);

sLight.castShadow = true;

sLight.shadowMapWidth = 1024;

sLight.shadowMapHeight = 1024;

sLight.shadowCameraNear = 300;

sLight.shadowCameraFar = 600;

sLight.shadowCameraFov = 45;

scene.add(sLight);
```

Answer (score 0):

I have had a similar problem.

I don't know why this happens, but I solved it changing the planeGeometry to a cubeGeometry (in the plane casting the shadow)

Answer (score 0):

See https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/9315

Set

```
renderer.shadowMap.renderReverseSided = false
```

or/and

```
renderer.shadowMap.renderSingleSided = false
```

can solve the problem.

When disabled, an appropriate shadow.bias must be set on the light source for surfaces that can both cast and receive shadows at the same time to render correctly:

```
let dl = new THREE.DirectionalLight()
dl.shadow.bias = -0.0001
```

*three.js r.85*