# Three js Light through transparent plane .. Shadow

Tags: three.js

Is ist possible to have three js send light through a transparent object?

I have a plane with a cloud. The Light (sun) is above the cloud and below the cloud plane a shadow is hitting another (terrain) plane. But sadly the shape is the one of the Mesh (rectangle) not the one of the cloud. I understand why the shadow is rectangular but is there any way to create the wanted effect?

you can see the example [here](http://mu5ic.de/juni_scene_1.html)

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16246023/shadowmap-texture-alpha

Comment: Tip: use `OrbitControls` in your demo so the scene will remain right-side-up.