# Wireframe and Shadows

Tags: three.js

I'm working my way through the good intro Packt book "Learning Threee.js..." by Jos Dirksen.

On page39 he discusses the chapter-02/01-basicscene.html file and shows rendering a series of cubes with shadows. The example works fine solid objects but I when I make the cubes wireframe;

var cubeMaterial = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({color:  Math.random() * 0xffffff, wireframe: true });

I still see solid shadows on the plane.

Is this a known problem or is there a way of seeing just the wireframe shadows?

Thanks

Graham

Answer (score 1):

It's a feature. :-)

When casting shadows, objects are treated as solid from the point of view of the light.

See this related post: [Shadowmap texture alpha](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16246023/shadowmap-texture-alpha).

three.js r.66